# What to put in database columns when creating registration/login system? (xampp)

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, lampp

I'm running the following through xampp. (Copying it and placing it in the htdocs)
https://github.com/fethica/PHP-Login

It says to “Create database "login" and create tables ‘members’ and ‘loginAttempts’”

Sounds easy, i created that, but then mysql wants columns and column names. And wont save unless i put something there. What usually goes there?

Answer (score 0):

The code below (which is contained within the link you have provided) is the schema you can execute as is (which will generate the tables for you). This shows the columns and column names you would need to include, I have noted which columns you would need to include:

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (
  `id` char(23) NOT NULL, /* INCLUDE THIS COLUMN */
  `username` varchar(65) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', /* INCLUDE THIS COLUMN */
  `password` varchar(65) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', /* INCLUDE THIS COLUMN */
  `email` varchar(65) NOT NULL, /* INCLUDE THIS COLUMN */
  `verified` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', /* INCLUDE THIS COLUMN */
  `mod_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, /* INCLUDE THIS COLUMN */
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username_UNIQUE` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email_UNIQUE` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `loginAttempts` (
  `IP` varchar(20) NOT NULL, /* INCLUDE THIS COLUMN */
  `Attempts` int(11) NOT NULL, /* INCLUDE THIS COLUMN */
  `LastLogin` datetime NOT NULL, /* INCLUDE THIS COLUMN */
  `Username` varchar(65) DEFAULT NULL, /* INCLUDE THIS COLUMN */
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, /* INCLUDE THIS COLUMN */
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, i missed that. Do you know how can run that block

Answer (score 0):

Read the PHPLogin help, require specific database schema:

https://github.com/fethica/PHP-Login#creating-the-mysql-database

If you are using mysql execute the following statements in your database:

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (
  `id` char(23) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(65) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(65) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(65) NOT NULL,
  `verified` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `mod_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username_UNIQUE` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email_UNIQUE` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `loginAttempts` (
  `IP` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Attempts` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LastLogin` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Username` varchar(65) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

otherwise create it manually

Comment: Ah, sorry, i missed that. What is that in?